# Aggregate previously classified items taking into account precision&recall

Tags: probability, precision-recall, aggregation, sentiment-analysis

I have a set of messages classified in k categories using sentiment analysis. I have also the precision, recall and accuracy of the classification technique for each category.

Now I would like to group messages by user (each message as a user). For instance, some user u can have 3 messages classified as k1, 2 messages classified as k2, and 5 messages classified as k3.

Is there any standard way of indicating how much is the user involved in each category? Obviously I could say that she uses k1-messages the 30%, k2-messages the 20% and k3-messages the 50%, but this does not consider the precision/recall of the previous classification.

That is, I would like to obtain an estimation of the ratio of messages by user and category, and if possible with some measure of the "quality" of this result. For instance, it would be great to have a result like:

"user u : k1 -> [0.1,0.3], k2->[0.25, 0.5], k3->[0.4,0.97] with alfa = 0.05"

Is this possible?